# How can I install the latest version of cloud ops agent on Ubuntu?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ops-agent

I faced with the issue that cloud-ops-agent consumes too much of the CPU, so I'd like to update a version of it (I found that it was a known issue for certain version). Right now I have version `2.22.0` and I'd like to update it to the latest one (`2.28.0`). I used command from the official google docs:

```
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh
sudo bash add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh --also-install
```

But this installs version `2.24.0`
And I can see that Debian/Ubuntu repositories indeed have the only `2.24.0` version.
[image]
I'm using `Linux Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)` and unless I'm missing something there is no restriction of using v`2.28.0` on that OS version. So, my question - is there any alternative way to install the latest version?
I'd appreciate any advice)

Answer (score 0):

You can install a specific version using the [--version flag](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/installation) or this command

```
sudo bash add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh --also-install --version=MAJOR_VERSION.*.*
```

just replace the `MAJOR_VERSION.*.*` with the desired version of the Ops Agent

then check the [installed version](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/installation#agent-version) using

```
dpkg-query --show --showformat '${Package} ${Version} ${Architecture} ${Status}\n' google-cloud-ops-agent
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, but unfortunately I still have the same problem.
I tried to run `sudo bash add-google-cloud-ops-agent-repo.sh --also-install --version=2.28.0` and I'm getting the following error `E: Version '2.28.0~*' for 'google-cloud-ops-agent' was not found`.

Comment: If you have the old agents installed, you should complete the [uninstall steps for the Cloud Monitoring agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/monitoring/installation#uninstall) then re run the installation command